# Useeffect Is not called by database changes

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to run a simple code inside use effect. I have set a dependency on the database. So, according to rules when the database will be changed the use effect should be called automatically. But i updated the value of the rating, the use effect is not called. so the effect doesn't show me the updated value.

But if i press cntrl+ s then the use effect is called automatically and the updated value is hown>

Now, please help to solve my issue so that if I change anything database the use effect will be called automatically.
here is the code

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('testt--222------------------')
    database.ref(`courselist/${CourseId}`)
        .child('courseReview')
        .orderByChild('rating')
        .equalTo(5)
        .once('value')
        .then(snapshot => {
            One = snapshot.numChildren();
            console.log('-------One-----', One);
            setonestarsum(((One / x) * 100));
            console.log('testt--------------------', One)
        });

}, [database]);
```

Comment: What is the other screen code that runs that you expect to trigger this effect.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Google Firebase? Otherwise it won't work, because useEffect can't check changes in your database.

Comment: yse , i'm using Google firebase . In my other screen the use effect is called by change of database. But this is from another screen which should be called by the updated of ratings but doesn't it.

Comment: Can you try using the following instead of .then(snapshot =>:
      .onSnapshot(
        (querySnapshot) => {
          const One = querySnapshot.docs.map((documentSnapshot) => {
          const data = documentSnapshot.data();
     }